# How client gets DNS server address?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, linux-networking

I understand we can get DNS server details via DHCP when we first establish connection with our router.

But what if the router is not configured for the DNS server address and even the client is not configured manually for DNS server address.

How will the request for resolving a url is transmitted ? or will it result in an error ?

Comment: It simply won't resolve.

Comment: Except you have configured the host you want to connect to in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @Sven: Suppose the client didn't request DNS server ip during first DHCP request, how can it ask the router/gateway for DNS server the next time it needs to resolve a name?

Comment: @DwayneSmith: Please note: Do not crosspost the same question to multiple SE sites. This is not welcome. Please check the various sites help centers to learn were it will fit best and only post there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DHCP client doesn't request DNS servers from the DHCP server. The DHCP server assigns DNS servers to the client. If the DHCP server isn't configured to assign DNS servers to the DHCP client then the DHCP client will not have DNS servers. If the DHCP server is later configured to assign DNS servers to the DHCP client then the DHCP client will get those DNS servers then next time the DHCP client refreshes/renews it's DHCP ip address lease.

Comment: Okay, so it is simple that if DNS parameters were not assigned to the DHCP client by the server initially and the client doesn't even have a hosts file or anything configured locally then there won't be any name resolution. Is that right ?   Also, is there any protocol or possibility that client sends a kind of broadcast to get DNS server details from hosts within same subnet or from internet ?

Comment: @DwayneSmith: `Also, is there any protocol or possibility that client sends a kind of broadcast to get DNS server details from hosts within same subnet`. This is what DHCP is for (among other things). Either configure your DHCP system correctly or manually configure name resolution on your host. There is just no need for a third way.

Comment: Also, what you suggest would by design be nothing but a new possibility for easy MITM attacks. Forget it.